# How to check if incoming stream is screen stream or camera stream

Tags: webrtc, streaming, agora.io

I am using agora video call sdk to develop a conference system with screen sharing feature.
After subscribing the stream how can I detect the source of stream, whether it is screen stream or camera stream.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** I was searching something like stream.hasVideo(), and I tried stream.hasScreen() but it is returning false every time whether stream source is camera or screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a solution which makes use of the RTM SDK. You can set a variable and send a message to all users mentioning the type of stream which was published.

When a client stream is published, set the user's stream type to something like 1 and 0 if their screen stream is published and 2 if both are published.

When this message is sent by a user to all other users, the other users will know what stream he/she was given by the 1st user.

Comment: Already using this solution but failed, as RTM failed to publish messages to all users due to latency or network issue many times. Stream is subscribed by the user before RTM message is received as both are independent services.

Comment: Could you share any code for that? RTM doesn’t usually malfunction that much.